# How to Find Last Deployment Date of SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I manage our SSRS Report Server and I'm curious if there is a way to find out the last date a report was deployed to the report server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Catalog and Users (assuming you want to know who did the change) tables to get this info.

```
SELECT 
    c.[Path], c.Name
    , c.CreationDate
    ,  cu.UserName
    , c.ModifiedDate
    , cm.UserName
    FROM [Catalog] c 
        JOIN Users cu on cu.UserID = c.CreatedByID
        JOIN Users cm on cm.UserID = c.ModifiedByID
```